# I implemented Android SIP sample to audio and video calling but getting Registration failed

Tags: android, sip

I Download demo from github and implemented but i'm not able to login and registration .

Can any body help me with this.It will very gladly.

https://github.com/ketanpatel25/SIP-Demo

Comment: What are the details you are filling in for username,domain and password ?

Comment: username:113355678
password:113355678
domain:sip.antisip.com

Answer (score 1):

In order to register on a SIP server you should provide IP address of your SIP server (Asterisk, Kamailio, FreeSwitch, etc) your SIP username and password (depending on your server configuration username/password maybe optional). For testing purpose you can setup Asterisk or use free SIP services like [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/free-sip-service.html?page=free-sip-service.html). Notice that Linphone also provides a very good open-source client and library that you can integrate into your project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the your user id and password is correct? Registration failure could be of Incorrect/ Deactivated UserId-Password combo. Try getting a fresh SIP credentials from Free provides like [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/free-sip-service.html?page=free-sip-service.html) and use in your app.

Comment: Yes,Login credentials is correct i got this credentials from product manager of sip by mail

Comment: Did you verify it ?? Install Zoiper or Xlite or Linphone in your Computer machine and put your credentials to verify it is registering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for SIP demo application i suggest you can opt from these 
mentioned below

1. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SipDemo/
2. https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/SipDemo
3. https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SipDemo

Comment: I am thanking to you,But i already implemented above all demo didn't complete audio or video functionality.